# Laravel 5, Form::select - Dropdown select 'other'

Tags: forms, laravel, select, dropdown

im working on a Laravel 5 Site and implemented a Form with a DropDown menu. All works fine but the user should be able to select the option "Other" and write his own Text.
I've googled and found some good ideas but i can't implement it.
here's what i got:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('special_status', 'Erasmus, Nebenhöhrer:') !!}
    {!! Form::select('special_status',$status, null, ['id' => 'special_status', 'class' => 'form-control', 'dropdown-menu']) !!}
</div>
```

with the

```
$status = array (
        'Erasmus'     => 'Erasmus',
        'NebenhörerIn'=> 'NebenhörerIn',
        'Sonstiges'   =>  'Sonstiges',
    );
```

An example how it should be: 
http://jsfiddle.net/CxV9c/4/

And here's what i find on StOverf: 
[Laravel 4 - Assign OnChange to Form::select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481319/laravel-4-assign-onchange-to-formselect)

Running Laravel 5.2.22 - Homestead
Includes:

```
bootstrap.min.css
jquery.min.js
bootstrap.min.js
```

Thx,

Pat

Comment: So what is your specific problem?

Comment: By click on "Sonstiges" it should be open a textbox where the user can input his own answear. I don't know how to implement Javascript into the Form:select.

Comment: But in the fiddle example, I can see that was implemented to show/hide the input.

Comment: Yes in a simple example, but how to implement this elegant to my .blade like this: {!! Form::select( 'name', $options, 'default', array('onchange' => 'doSomething(this)') ) !!}

Comment: Here is another example, but is don't know how to implement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993691/laravel-blade-form-is-it-possible-to-create-a-textbox-input-if-a-user-selects-t

Comment: Hey Alpha, thank you for your tips. Maybe there will be a few more questions in future ;-) Greetings from Berlin Pat. p.s.: actually don't know how to write personal messages...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you can just put a `script` tag in your `blade` view, for example:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("input[type=text]").hide();
        $('#visit').on('change', function () {
            var v = this.value == 4 ? 'show' : 'hide';
            $.fn[v].call($("input[type=text]"));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Just put this snippet at the bottom of your blade view. Also, make sure you've added the [jQuery](https://jquery.com/download/) library vefore this script runs. This is the simplest way but there are other ways to add one or more `script` tags in a blade view. A working [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/CxV9c/356/).